# Modfying state in React using Onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im very new to React, just wanted to make a simple program that has multiple buttons that correspond to some value in state, what i want is when a button is pressed, the respective value negates

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state={
            a: true,
            b: false,
            c: true,
            d: false
        }
        this.handleAction = this.handleAction.bind(this);
        }
        handleAction(action) {
            this.setState({
                name: !this.state.name

            });

        }
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name='a'/>
                        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name='b'/>
                        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name='c'/>
                        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name='d'/>
                    </div>
                )
            }

    }
    function Child({onAction, name}){
        return (
            <button onClick={onAction}>
             {name}
            </button>
        );
    }
```

is there a way to do this without 4 separate handleAction functions ? i tried passing `name` to `onAction` but that throws `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded`

i know there must be something really obvious that i'm missing, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `name` as a parameter to your `handleAction` function

```js
....
handleAction(name) {
    this.setState( state => ({ [name]: !state[name] }) );
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Child onAction={() => this.handleAction('a')} name='a'/>
            <Child onAction={() => this.handleAction('b')} name='b'/>
            <Child onAction={() => this.handleAction('c')} name='c'/>
            <Child onAction={() => this.handleAction('d')} name='d'/>
        </div>
    )
}
...
```

Note that reading from `this.state` inside `this.setState` isn't good practice. [see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: this works, Thank you, can you please explain the reason behind returning another function like you've done before `handleAction` and others have done inside of it instead of directly modifying the state like i did?

Comment: Sure! the reason for not using `this.state` directly inside `setState` is that `setState` is async in nature, which means that `setState` isn't immediately applied. Though it's unlikely here, there's a risk that if  you call `setState` twice, both of them could find the same value in `this.state`, since the `setState` may not have been applied yet. The function style update,  `this.setState(state => ...)` stops you from reading stale values from `this.state`. You can find a detailed example in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear i meant on the added on `()=>` in your `onAction={() => this.handleAction('a')} `

Answer (score 1):

Change the handler so that it can accept name and return another function.

```
  handleAction(name) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({
        [name]: !this.state[name],
      });
    };
  }
```

In child component pass the name of that child

```
 <Child onAction={this.handleAction("a")} name='a'/>
```

Comment: Accessing `this.state` inside a `setState` is strongly discouraged in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      a: true,
      b: false,
      c: true,
      d: false,
    };
    this.handleAction = this.handleAction.bind(this);
  }
  handleAction(name) {
    return () => {
      console.log("name", name);
      this.setState({
        [name]: !this.state[name],
      });
    };
  }
  render() {
    console.log("this.state", this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name="a" />
        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name="b" />
        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name="c" />
        <Child onAction={this.handleAction} name="d" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function Child({ onAction, name }) {
  return <button onClick={onAction(name)}>{name}</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you want to use the name of the button and then to change the state with the same name. First, you should provide the name of the button to the function. As the event is passed to the function by default, you can get the name for example like this:

```
event.target.innerText
```

Then, if you use the name as variable containing the value you must use [name] notation. Otherwise, it will add the 'name' property to your object.
As the result your handler should look like this:

```
handleAction(e) {
  const name = e.target.innerText
  this.setState({
      [name]: !this.state[name]
  });
}
```